# Grabbing String From Nested Array Using Nested Loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-for-loop

I am a totally new to coding and I'm practicing loops and arrays. I created an array with multiple sub arrays that contain pairs of strings. I'm trying to pull out and isolate each string using a nested for loops.
Here is my code:

```
const pairs = [['Blue', 'Green'],['Red', 'Orange'],['Pink', 'Purple']];

//attempting to use nested arrays to get each string from an array 
function getString(arr){
    //this loop should grab each array in the list of arrays
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        console.log(i , arr[i]);
        //this should assign each sub array to a new var to be iterated over
        subArr = arr[i];
    } for (let j = 0; j < subArr.length; j++){
        console.log(j, arr[j]);
    }
};


console.log(getString(pairs));
```

the problem is the output is of the last for loop is : ['Pink', 'Purple'] not each color extracted from the nested loops.

What am I doing wrong here?

- Mirii

Comment: What is the output you are expecting ?

Comment: Do you want to return the array result or you just want to show them to the console?

Comment: You have nested array. When you are using first for loop, you are just accessing the inner array. You need to have one more loop to read the value of this array.

Comment: I am trying to pull out each string and put them into a new array and print it

Answer (score 1):

Your loops aren't actually nested: you close the first loop before starting the second one. Because `subArr` is a global varialbe (no `let`, `const`, or `var` keyword), it's still defined in the second loop, but that's not an ideal way to do things. You also need to log `arr[i][j]` rather than what you have.

This fixes those issues:

```
function getString(arr) {
  //this loop should grab each array in the list of arrays
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    //this should assign each sub array to a new var to be iterated over
    let subArr = arr[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < subArr.length; j++){
      console.log(arr[i][j]);
    }
  }
};
getString(pairs);
```

Another issue you have is that you're calling `console.log(getString(pairs))`, but `getString` doesn't return anything, it's logging itself. If you want it to return, for example, a newline-delimited string of all the items, you could push items to an array and return them joined with a newline (or whatever character you want):

```
function getString(arr) {
  let ret = []
  //this loop should grab each array in the list of arrays
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    //this should assign each sub array to a new var to be iterated over
    let subArr = arr[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < subArr.length; j++){
      ret.push(arr[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return ret.join('\n')
};

console.log(getString(pairs));
```

Nested loops themselves aren't ideal, since they're not as readable as using array methods. Using `forEach` takes much less code:

```
function getString (arr) {
  arr.forEach(function (subArr) {
    console.log(subArr[0])
    console.log(subArr[1])
  })
}

getString(pairs)
```

Or, more succinctly, you can use `map`:

```
function getString (arr) {
  return arr.map(([ a, b ]) => `${a}\n${b}`).join('\n');
}
console.log(getString(pairs))
```

Even more succinctly, you can do this with `[].flat()`:

```
const getString = (xs = []) => xs.flat().join('\n')
console.log(getString(pairs))
```

Comment: wow thank you for the insight! I knew it was the way I was writing them. I looked up map and flat I'm still trying to figure out how to use them the MDN reference on them is a bit jargony haha!

Answer (score 0):

You should nest the `for` loops like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(i, arr[i]);
  //this should assign each sub array to a new var to be iterated over
  subArr = arr[i];

  for (let j = 0; j < subArr.length; j++) {
    console.log(j, arr[j]);
  }
}
```

How you have it, they'd run one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution is provided**
:

```
function getString(arr) {
  let arrResult = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      arrResult.push(arr[i][j]);
    }
  }

  return arrResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the loops, just like you are nesting the arrays. Also, unless you want to alter `i` or `j`, I suggest you use `.forEach` as it is more simple to work with.

Example:

```
pairs.forEach((pair, i) => {
  pair.forEach((subPair, j) => {
    console.log(j, subPair);
  });
});
```

You may also make a variable, push to it within the `pair.forEach` function, and return it at the end of your root function.

I hope this answers your question, thank you for posting, and have a nice day. ;P